# Touch and hold in iOS app to copy chat URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, ios-app

On iOS, I use a browser other than Chrome or Safari, and as a result I can't open notifications that link to chat.

[image: chat notification]

I'd like to see the commonly-used gesture of touch & hold to get a link to the URL so can I navigate in my browser.  This should also work in the Feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A weird web browser you say? To each his own, I guess.  This'll be in the next build.

As a side note, `-tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` only gets called for standard actions so you have to implement `-canPerformAction:withSender:` in your cell.  That said, you still have to implement `-tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:` for the menu to appear at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip (and the feature)!